# Something wrong with video card drivers

Tags: ubuntu-drivers

I am using Ubuntu Bionic 18.04, and while I am watching video, It freezes once in every 30 seconds, I think I didn't install drivers properly. Does anyone know what causes the problem, and how I can solve it? Thanks.

00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 06)
    Subsystem: Lenovo 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller
    Kernel driver in use: i915

### Kernel modules: i915

01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GM107M [GeForce GTX 860M] (rev a2)
    Subsystem: Lenovo GM107M [GeForce GTX 860M]
    Kernel driver in use: nouveau
    Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'` terminal command.

Comment: I edited my question